# difference between why should I and why I should

Tags: usage, word-order

> Why should boys have all the fun?
>   Why boys should have all the fun?

Please help me with the difference.

Comment: The difference is that one is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is a grammatical question in English.

The second is not (except in special contexts: You might see it in a title of an article, probably without a query on the end: it would be elliptic for something like "The question of why boys should have all the fun". Titles and headlines actually have their own grammar).

Comment: Not just titles. You can have ordinary questions like "Can you tell me why boys should have all the fun?"

Comment: Yes, you can, @MrLister, but except in titles the abbreviated form (without the matrix sentence) doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

The question format is

Wh-Question/Question Phrase + Auxilary Verb + Subject + Other part

According to the question structure, the question should be:

```
Why should boys have all the fun?
```